# How to send an email to existing email address in Firebase realtime dataset

Tags: javascript, firebase, nodemailer

so I have this Realtime Database on Firebase which contains an email address, I wish to send an email to those address automatically. I Intend to use nodemailer, but every solution that I found online sends the email on request. Here I provide my database and code. Any solutions to modify the code so that I can send the email to every address on my database? Thank you very much for answering

[image: my database]

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp();

/**
* Here we're using Gmail to send 
*/
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: '',
        pass: ''
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
      
        // getting dest email by query string
        const dest = req.query.dest;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: '', 
            to: dest,
            subject: '', 
            html: `` 
        };
  
        // returning result
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if(erro){
                return res.send(erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sended');
        });
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have some trigger or event when you need to send the mail.
For, e.g. whenever a new user signs up, and a node is created, you need to send a *welcome email*.

If you need in the case, I stated above - you can use Firebase Realtime Database triggers for it.
An onCreate trigger would be:

```
functions.database.ref(_YOUR_PATH_).onCreate(event => {
     // do your function i.e. send email
});
```

For more info you can refer here: [Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

And if you need to have all the emails in a scheduled manner (*once in a month or so*)- you can use a [Cron-Job](https://cron-job.org/en/)

Here is a suitable example for your case: [Send Confirmation Emails with Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation)